# Where in Chengdu can we see Sanxingdui artifacts, besides the museum in Guanghan?

Tags: online-resources, china, sightseeing, museums

I visited Chengdu a few years ago, and a friend who plans to visit recently asked me for advice about things to see there.

One thing that looks interesting is the Sanxingdui ancient culture and its artifacts – large bronze masks that look like alien creatures, etc.  There is a well-known museum called the Sanxingdui Museum near the excavation site in Guanghan, north of Chengdu city.  However, Google Maps also shows a “Sanxingdui Art Museum” in the center of town, across the street from the Wuhou (Zhuge Liang) Temple.  This would be convenient, but it’s difficult to find more detailed information about it online.  I have been to neither museum myself.

My question:  Given that my friend may not have time to make a special trip outside the city, how does the collection at the latter museum compare to that in the Sanxingdui Museum?  Will it give a person interested in archeology a good picture of this ancient culture, or is it necessary to go out to Guanghan?  Or perhaps there are other museums in Chengdu with good collections of Sanxingdui artifacts.

Comment: I'd err against trusting Google Maps in this case.  The address for the "Sanxingdui Art Museum" seems to be lifted from [this article](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/things-chengdu-china-63824.html), which actually describes the same Sanxingdui Museum, and [the website Google shows for it is a Chinese design company](http://www.cdsxd.com/).  It looks like your friend might have to head out of town.

Comment: I agree with the comment by dlanod. Checking the map/street view of Baidu (the Chinese Google) for this place reveals a 三星堆玉器, SanXingDui jadeware. Given the location in a shopping area, it seems to be a store for sanxingdui inspired ornaments. http://map.baidu.com/#panoid=0501920000140910064831935SB&panotype=street&heading=141.91&pitch=7.93&l=17&tn=B_NORMAL_MAP&sc=0&newmap=1&shareurl=1&pid=0501920000140910064831935SB

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**There is no SanXingDui art museum in Chengdu, you have to go to GuangHan. The "museum" displayed by google maps is a store.**

Source: I asked friends. They confirm that the place in the streetview below at the location reported by google is a store and that the real museum is the one out of town in GuangHan.

Details:
Google does report a SanXingDui art museum in the city across from the WuHou park but as @dlanod points out in his excellent comment "the address [...] seems to be lifted from [this article](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/things-chengdu-china-63824.html) which actually describes the same Sanxingdui Museum [i.e. the one in GuangHan], and [the website Google shows for it is a Chinese design company](http://www.cdsxd.com/)." [actually the website is down right now for me.]
Checking the map/street view of Baidu (the Chinese Google) for this place reveals a 三星堆玉器, SanXingDui jadeware. Given the location in a shopping area, it seems to be a store for sanxingdui inspired ornaments. [Here is a streetview](http://map.baidu.com/#panoid=0501920000140910064831935SB&panotype=street&heading=141.91&pitch=7.93&l=17&tn=B_NORMAL_MAP&sc=0&newmap=1&shareurl=1&pid=0501920000140910064831935SB). Two friends from the area confirmed that this is merely a store. I reported the wrong listing to Google three months ago but nothing had changed as of today.

The *good* museum is [the one in GuangHan](http://sxd.cn/en/index.html), 29km out of Chengdu.

Update: A friend send me a picture that shows a sign for a 三星堆艺术馆 (SanXingDui museum) [here](http://map.baidu.com/#panoid=0501920000140910064833717SB&panotype=street&heading=183.26&pitch=-5.17&l=4&tn=B_NORMAL_MAP&sc=0&newmap=1&shareurl=1&pid=0501920000140910064833717SB). However, as of [this Chinese forum Q&A](http://zhidao.baidu.com/link?url=1Ik36il1QlMtTweU2bfr4ELuqHdwPnZwkolz_itKB5Yxf9Zkl6_wBPUZW14v9Nl_OnCrxtjFjccLMSySvwqX4SEzsGy0LDa2MBvIIbUDAhW) that is only a sign with nothing behind it as of 2014:

> Q: 三星堆艺术馆怎么样
>   A: 问了保安，说是已经没有了。只有一个空招牌而已。

Very loose translation of mine:
"What is the 三星堆艺术馆 (SanXingDui museum) like?"
"Watch out. It does not (/no longer) exist. There is only an empty sign."